# Spring Boot MVC war logging not writing to catalina.ot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I have a standard Spring Boot 2.0.4 MVC.  It is not a standalone jar, it is a war that is deployed to a tomcat 8.5.something container.  here is my pom:

```
<dependencies> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and my application.properties has this:

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.com.me=DEBUG
```

But none of my logging statements are in catalina.out  I even tried:

```
  logging.file = /home/michael/mylogfile.log
```

but no file was created.

I googled this all but only found embedded tomcat examples.  I'm sure I missed a config element somewhere.  This is the simple logging example,  but I can't get it to work!

**UPDATE**
I added this to mu pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But still no luck

Comment: Did you add any logging framework (or provider) in your dependency?

Comment: No,  I was under the impression that Spring used logback that came with Spring.  I was basically going off this:  https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-slf4j-logging-example/